# How to set up my routing that "pathMatch" and childRoutingModule work?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, single-page-application

1. On the left-side menu I need to have the links highlighted when the user on them. Now it works but my root path 'li' of the menu is highlighted as well.
2. I cannot set up a child routing Module.

left-side-menu html

```
<ul class='side-menu'>
  <li *ngFor='let item of menu' routerLinkActive='active-side-menu-item'><a routerLink='{{ item.link }}' class="menu-item-feed">{{ item.title }}</a></li>
</ul>
```

app.routing.module ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { FeedComponent } from './feed/feed.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', component: FeedComponent },
  { path: 'shoes', pathMatch: 'full', component: FeedComponent },
  { path: 'coats', pathMatch: 'full', component: FeedComponent },
  { path: 'shirts', pathMatch: 'full', component: FeedComponent },
  { path: 'pants', pathMatch: 'full', component: FeedComponent },
  { path: 'item/:id', component: FeedComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

That's how I tried to implement my childRoutingModule but it throws the error in the console: core.js:15724 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: undefined is not a function
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Array.map ()

app.routing.module

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', loadChildren: './feed/feed.module#FeedModule' }
];
```

feed-routing.module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { FeedComponent } from './feed.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', component: FeedComponent },
  { path: 'shoes', pathMatch: 'full', component: FeedComponent },
  { path: 'coats', pathMatch: 'full', component: FeedComponent },
  { path: 'shirts', pathMatch: 'full', component: FeedComponent },
  { path: 'pants', pathMatch: 'full', component: FeedComponent },
  { path: 'item/:id', component: FeedComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class FeedRoutingModule { }
```

I want to have a separate routing module for each gross section on the site and I need link react to the url and indicate which module is active at the moment.

I would appreciate any other hints and best practices!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To setup feature route you have to import FeedRoutingModule into the module you want to use thoose route.

Below is my example

I have app.routing.ts (Main route)

```js
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "", redirectTo: "home", pathMatch: "full" },
  { path: "home", component: HomeComponent },

  //{ path: "**", redirectTo: "account", pathMatch: "full" },
  //lazy load feature module
  { path: "account", loadChildren: "./account/account.module#AccountModule" },
  { path: "portal", loadChildren: "./portal/portal.module#PortalModule", canActivate: [AuthGuardService] },
  { path: "**", redirectTo: "account", pathMatch: "full" },
];
```

and app.module.ts

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: []
})
export class AppModule {}
```

So when I define child route in my feature module I have to done the same like app.module but using RouterModule.forChild

```
export const accountRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    component: AccountComponent,
    children: [
      { path: "login", component: LoginComponent },
      { path: "register-account", component: RegisterComponent }
    ]
  }
];
```

```js
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { RouterModule } from "@angular/router";

import { RegisterComponent } from "./register/register.component";
import { LoginComponent } from "./login/login.component";
import { AccountComponent } from "./account/account.component";
import { accountRoutes } from "./account.routing";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(accountRoutes) // use forChild
  ],
  exports: [],
  providers: []
})
export class AccountModule {}
```

Comment: Actually I’ve done all the same except children paths, but I doubt that’s the issue because before it worked for me without children paths well. Didn’t you notice where I’ve made a mistake or something?

Comment: Thank you, my friend! Finally, I've found my mistake. I didn't get what you meant at first but now I've got that I added my FeedMudule to my App.module what caused that error. I shouldn't have added it there :S apparently

Comment: Yeah, at first I didn’t notice that you didn’t import the CustomModule in the App.module but today I’ve opened one of my previous projects and darted a glance of how I implemented routing there, and I noticed that there I didn’t import custom modules :D then I came back to your code and noticed that you didn’t import them either. Yesterday I examined the code so much that didn’t see the difference between my code and yours. I hope I won’t have such silly mistakes again XD lost a day trying to solve such a dummy mistake

Answer (score 0):

Your paranet component need have tag: 

```
< router-outlet>< /router-outlet>
```

 then he knows will have a child component + route;

Here a exemple where i management childRoutes.

```
    {
      path: 'utente',
      component: CenterViewComponent,
      children: [
           YYY_ROUTE,
           XXX_ROUTE
           ...
      ]
    }
```

Hope help u!

Comment: As I can see you implemented that childRouting with children attribute in the app.routing.module, right? I didn’t try this way actually. But interesting if it works in my case. I have the “router-outlet” tag in the root. But loadChildren doesn’t work. :/ don’t you know why? I bet there is a very silly mistake because I’ve done that many times before but this time it doesn’t work 

Comment: Yes, i have all in one place. 
each component have your own route file. 


import { Route } from '@angular/router';
import { MainRegisterComponent } from '.';

export const MAIN_REGISTER_ROUTE: Route = {
  path: 'main-register',
  component: MainRegisterComponent
};

then i import this to my main route.
and you can have child's here.

Comment: I want to understand why I’ve got that error in my case with separate routing modules where I loadChildren in the main app.routing.module

Comment: Thanks for your answer, my friend! I've found my mistake, finally :D

Comment: with such a silly mistake lost a day)) such days aren't that inspiring